# Rails Multiple join query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have the below Model structure

```
class Transaction
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end

class Company
  belongs_to :address
end

class User
  belongs_to :address
end

classAddress
 has_many :companies
 has_many :users
end
```

I want to query all transactions and get both company address and user address

```
 Transaction.joins([company: :address], [user: :address])
    .select('company.addresses.line_1 as company_add_line1', 
       'user.addresses.line_1 as user_add_line1')
```

For the syntax 'company.addresses.line_1', I am getting the below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'company.addresses.line_1' in 'field list'
```

How t achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I note that your User and Company each should `have_many :transactions`

Your syntax fails b/c you have ActiveRecord-like syntax (e.g. `companies.addresses.line1` inside a SQL snippet)

You need something like this...

```rb
select_user_add = <<-SEL
  (select line1 
   from addresses
   joins users
     on users.address_id = addresses.id
   where transaction.user_id = users.id ) as user_add_line1
  SEL

select_company_add = <<-SEL
  (select line1 
   from addresses
   joins companies
     on companies.address_id = addresses.id
   where transaction.user_id = companies.id ) as company_add_line1
  SEL

Transaction.select("transactions.*, #{select_user_add}, #{select_company_add")
```

Comment: Isn't there a way I can achieve this via ActiveRecord?

Comment: I don't know of a way to use purely ActiveRecord. In my experience there are a few scenarios like this that AR does not address.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned **has_many :transactions** in the company and users model.

Cross-check the field with your schema fields this will work.

```
transaction_id = 1  # actual transaction ID

transaction_data = Transaction.joins(company: :address, user: :address)
                           .where(transactions: { id: transaction_id })
                           .select('transactions.*, companies.*, users.*',
                                   'company_addresses.line_1 as company_add_line1',
                                   'user_addresses.line_1 as user_add_line1')
                           .first
```